# Kinematics equations: wrong place value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A marble is launched horizontally off a 93.0 cm high table causing the marble to land on the floor 1.85 m from the
base of the table.
a.) How long was the ball in the air?
b.) With what velocity must the marble have left the tabletop?

So this requires t and V0 of the X component. I did some math, and I got t = 4.35 instead of the correct 0.435.
I used the formula (V_y)^2 = (V_0y)^2 + 2a_y * Delta y.
V^2 = V0^2 + 2aΔx.

Using that formula, I solve for V^2 and I plug in 0 for V0 and -9.8 for a and 93 for Δx.

I get 4.35. I should get 0.435.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: $\Delta x$ was 93 metres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong units. You used the value g = 9.8m/s^2, but you used 93cm for Δy (Δx was a mistake, the table is 93cm *high*, not long). That is wrong. Before performing the equation, convert the height of the table to 0.93 metres, and you will find that the time to fall comes out at 0.435s. Units are extremely important. I hope this helped answer your question.